# Heroku gets error with Ruby Mongrel gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongrel

Can't quite find the answer for my error in related posts.

I'm working my way through the on-line version of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial, Chapter 2 
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#top

and I'm near the bottom where I've created a small 2-table database and committed it to git. But it fails when I try to deploy with 'git push heroku master'. The same command worked previously before I added the tables to the app (and before I got Mongrel to work on the demo_app, I think).

My bundle includes Ruby 1.8.7, Mongrel 1.1.5 and sqlite3 1.3.3. I'm getting the line:

```
Installing mongrel (1.1.5) with native extensions /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in 'rescue in block in build_extensions':ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem:Installer::ExtensionBuildError).
```

How do I get around this problem? Can Heroku handle Mongrel at all? Or is it due to having a sqlite3 database? Why does the error mention Ruby1.9.2 when that's not in my bundle?

Comment: If the answer was succesful, please accept it.

Comment: @nathanvda Alright, I have to ask. You took the time to tell the newbie to accept the answer, but you didn't bother to vote up that same answer. Why not?

Comment: @jdl I came here just because I browsed unanswered questions, to see if I can help. The question was answered already, so the OP should accept. Secondly, I vote up answers that either learn me new insights, or which are well formulated and which I know (or think) are correct. If I ask questions myself, I tend to always upvote all answers (if somewhat correctly or helpful). Your answer worked for the OP, but to be honest, I felt I could not judge your answer myself correctly.

Comment: It's cool. I just thought it was humorous, and wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use mongrel at all, and should simply remove it from your `Gemfile`. Whenever you see a reference to starting mongrel in your tutorial, just use `./script/server` instead (or `rails server` if you're on Rails 3). It will run WebBrick, and that's good enough for development work.

If you really want to retain mongrel for local use you can group it as follows in `Gemfile`.

```
group :development do
  gem "mongrel"
end
```

Note that you will likely still have to [tell Heroku to not bundle your development gems](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler#specifying_gems__groups) or you'll run into the same error. If you're on the Cedar stack, then just get rid of the mongrel gem entirely.